# Find Three Largest Integers in an array algorithm optimized solution?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I was doing this algorithm to find three integers WITHOUT sorting the input array and return a sorted array of the three largest integers in the input array. Duplicates are okay.

Is there a way to solve this without helper functions like how i did? Or maybe a more optimized solution?

```
function findThreeLargestNumbers(array) {


 let result = [null, null, null];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    updateLargest(result, array[i])
  }
  return result
}

function updateLargest(result, num) {
  if (!result[2] || num > result[2]) {
    shiftAndUpdate(result, num, 2)
  } else if (!result[1] || num > result[1]) {
    shiftAndUpdate(result, num, 1)
  } else if (!result[0] || num > result[0]) {
    shiftAndUpdate(result, num, 0)
  }
}

function shiftAndUpdate(array, num, index) {
  for (let i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
    if (i === index) {
      array[i] = num;
    } else {
      array[i] = array[i + 1];
    }
  }
}

console.log(findThreeLargestNumbers([141, 1, 17, -7, -17, -27, 18, 541, 8, 7, 7]));
```

Comment: do you want to mutate the original array?

Comment: thats okay too but idk if that is good practice

Comment: `shiftAndUpdate()` could should be able to use `array.splice()`.

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect

Comment: For a simple solution: copy the three first elements to an array of size 3, and sort them decreasingly (6 cases). Then try and insert all remaining elements: if smaller than the third, drop; otherwise, shift and insert. [As a micro-optimization, you can organize the tests in two comparisons per element rather than three.]

Comment: *"without helper functions"*: please define what that means. Are native methods/functions allowed? Are methods allowed that need a callback argument?

Comment: *"a more optimized solution?"*: do you mean that it performs the least comparisons, or that it runs fastest in JavaScript? These two goals may not result in the same code.

Comment: You are going to have a very hard time beating `top(3)` from https://www.npmjs.com/package/heap-js

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `N ≥ 3`,

```
B[0]:= A[0]

# First two, sorted
if A[1] ≥ A[0]
    B[1]:= B[0]; B[0]:= A[1]
else
    B[1]:= A[1]

# First three, sorted
if A[2] ≥ A[1]
    B[2]:= B[1]
    if A[2] ≥ A[0]
        B[1]:= B[0]; B[0]:= A[2]
    else
        B[1]:= A[2]
else
    B[2]:= A[2]

# Update the largest three, sorted
for i:= 3 to N-1
    if A[i] ≥ A[1]
        B[2]:= B[1]
        if A[i] ≥ A[0]
            B[1]:= B[0]; B[0]:= A[i]
        else
            B[1]:= A[i]
    else
        if A[i] ≥ A[2]
            B[2]:= A[i]
```

At worse `2N-3` comparisons and `2N-1` moves.